# Can I skip an attribute / field to be validated by ModelState.IsValid() in asp mvc 5 (C#)? or Assign a value to Hidden Field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am creating a web application based on ASP.Net MVC 5 (C#) and stuck on validation of specific type. Basically, I have 5 models whose objects I included in a View Model. One of these five models is included as List in the view model. Since these models have relation between them, foreign keys are implemented and I have annotated the foreign keys as Required because they must be there.

**Scenario**
Model Classes:
Client - Clients in Application
AddressOf - Address of properties and Clients
ClientPhone - Phones of Clients - has foreign key of Client
ClientEmail - Emails of Clients - has foreign key of Client
Consultant - Consultants to handle Clients in the management system

Now, I have fields in View.cshtml for the Client Object, Address Object, ClientPhone, ClientEmail and Dropdown list for Consultant. Excluding the field for ClientPhone.ClientCNIC and ClientEmail.ClientCNIC which are foreign keys and will be entered in the controller when I have entered data in the Client Table. ClientCNIC does have field in the View.cshtml but its coming from the Client Table. Since the ClientCNIC field (Foreign Key) in ClientPhone and ClientEmail has annotation [Required], it shows validation error.

**What I want is, allocate the value of the field created for Client.ClientCNIC to the attributes ClientPhone.ClientCNIC and ClientEmail.ClientCNIC.**

Thanks in advance!

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(ClientFormViewModel clientFormViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.error = "";

                var Client = clientFormViewModel.Client;
                var Email = clientFormViewModel.ClientEmail;
                var Address = clientFormViewModel.AddressOf;
                var phone = clientFormViewModel.ClientPhone;

                _context.addressof.Add(Address);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                Client.addressofId = _context.addressof.Select(e => e.addressofId).Max();
                _context.Clients.Add(Client);
                try
                {
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException)
                {
                    _context.addressof.Remove(Client.AddressOf);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.Duplicate = "Duplicate Client";
                    clientFormViewModel.Consultants = _context.Consultants.ToList();
                    return View("ClientForm", clientFormViewModel);
                }

                phone.ClientCNIC = Client.ClientCNIC;
                phone.PrimaryPhone = true;
                _context.ClientPhone.Add(phone);

                Email.ClientCNIC = Client.ClientCNIC;
                Email.PrimaryEmail = true;
                _context.clientemail.Add(Email);

                _context.SaveChanges();

                return Content("Successful!");
            }

            ViewBag.error = "Has Error";
            clientFormViewModel.Consultants = _context.Consultants.ToList();
            return View("ClientForm", clientFormViewModel);
        }


        public ActionResult New()
        {
            ViewBag.Type = "New Client";

            var address = new AddressOf();
            var client = new Client();
            var phone = new ClientPhone();
            var email = new ClientEmail();


            var viewModel = new ClientFormViewModel()
            {
                Client = client,
                ClientPhone = phone,
                ClientEmail = email,
                AddressOf = address,
                Consultants = _context.Consultants.ToList()
            };

            viewModel.ClientEmail.ClientCNIC = viewModel.Client.ClientCNIC;
            viewModel.ClientPhone.ClientCNIC = viewModel.Client.ClientCNIC;


            return View("ClientForm", viewModel);
        }
```

**ClientPhone - Model Class** - Same structure as ClientEmail

```
namespace ITCMS4
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [Table("ClientPhones")]
    public partial class ClientPhone
    {
        [Key] public int ClientPhoneId { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required] public bool PrimaryPhone { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Client"), ForeignKey("Client")] public string ClientCNIC { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to remove the `[Required]` attribute from the 'offending' properties, while making sure they are assigned proper values where needed. A ViewModel does not always have to enforce or mimic all data model rules by means of data annotation attributes, and this is a good example of that.

Another way would be to keep the attributes and [create a custom ModelBinder](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+create+a+custom+ModelBinder) for the `ClientFormViewModel` class, which you then make apply this 'assign this also to that' rule of yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "A ViewModel does not always have to enforce or mimic all data model rules by means of data annotation attributes, and this is a good example of that." From this, if you are assuming that I have Annotated ViewModel, then this is not the case. I have annotated the respective classes to reflect the Not Null in database. And the first solution already has applied as a workaround. However, I personally do not like workarounds rather than learning how should it be solved. I am looking into the second solution you suggested. :)